# NFC tutorial for Android other than API demo

Tags: android, nfc

I'm tooling around with my Nexus S and some MiFare tags and am trying to get together an application that simply reads and displays the ID of a tag.  I've looked through the API demo a few times and can't quite get my head around it; I think this is so because the demo includes code for faking tags for developers who don't have access to a real device.

What I need is a tutorial or similar on how to code NFC-based apps for Android, ideally just the required imports and the method that will return the data from a scanned tag.

Does anyone know this off the top of their head?

Comment: This post may be helpful: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078649/android-nfc-sample-demo-reads-only-fake-information-from-the-tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078649/android-nfc-sample-demo-reads-only-fake-information-from-the-tag)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Exactly for this.. I did some work.

http://mifareclassicdetectiononandroid.blogspot.com/2011/04/reading-mifare-classic-1k-from-android.html

Hope it helps.

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 12):

I wrote an in-depth tutorial on how to get started with NFC here for people who are interested in learning how to integrate NFC with their Android app:

http://www.jessechen.net/blog/how-to-nfc-on-the-android-platform/

Answer (score 9):

Here is some [resources](http://code.google.com/p/nfc-eclipse-plugin/wiki/GettingStartedAndroid) aimed at entry-level developers:

1. An [NFC boilerplate project](http://code.google.com/p/ndef-tools-for-android/downloads/list) for detecting, reading and writing NFC in Android.
2. The [NFC Eclipse plugin](http://code.google.com/p/nfc-eclipse-plugin/) for a graphical NDEF editor.
3. A [workshop](https://github.com/skjolber/Fagmote/tree/master/Android/Near%20Field%20Communications) exercise taking in excess of 1 hour (includes solution)

(shameless plug ;-))

What many tutorials get wrong is that they handle NDEF messages in a low-level way. Rather **go for a higher-level library** like [NDEF Tools for Android](http://code.google.com/p/ndef-tools-for-android/) than messing around with byte arrays.

Comment: Thank you for that.  All the tutorials I've seen so far work with raw byte arrays, which doesn't seem like it should be necessary for just a "Hello World"-level NFC app.  I wonder when Android will get a more pleasant API for this.

Comment: Thomas, I downloaded 'NDEF Tools for Android' and I see a .jar file, but how would I open that up into 'org.ndeftools.<what's needed>'? I am more accustomed to dragging java files, not dealing with a jar in this case.

Comment: Get one of the other downloads, which includes the .java source?