# What is the easiest way to pass a string between two phones in Android?

Tags: android, bluetooth, nfc, p2p, wifi-direct

With Android 4.1+, what would be the most simplistic way to pass a unique string to the sender->receiver, and then back receiver->sender?

Ex. 2-way communication using NFC with only one user pressing the "Touch to Beam" UI

Edit: I would like this to be accomplished without the need of a cellular connection so that Wifi tablets could perform this action as well

Comment: That is an interesting idea! Using NFC to initiate a sms that is bounced between two devices would technically work, however I would like this to be compatible with devices that don't have a cellular connection. I guess I should update my original post...

Comment: You could send push notifications to each other using Google Cloud Messaging, idk if that's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use wifi p2p (aka wifi direct) to set up a P2P local wifi network to do file transfer. You can read the official guide/draft [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifip2p.html) (code sample included, Android 4.0 or later required).

Or you can use NFC (see this [helper class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5155076/1233379), which helped me a lot).

Comment: NFC would be preferable, I would like to get around the users having to tap phones twice. What I have found, this wouldn't be possible above Android 2.3? or am I incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

@Comment WeldFire: Not entirely correct.
Android beam always needs a user action to transmit data (via NFC), see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13542697/making-nfc-beam-more-automatic).

If you need transmission via NFC, you need to use NFC host card emulation respectively tag reader, which is more complicated but allows transmission without user interaction (requires API19 = Android 4.4+), see [docu](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/hce.html).

It is also possible to have automatic wifi p2p connection, see [this blog](http://www.drjukka.com/blog/wordpress/?p=39) with [example code](https://github.com/DrJukka/MyWifiMesh). In my oppinion this is the easiest and best performing way to build a connection between to Android devices without user interaction.